# Minecraft 1.13.2 keeps crashing when I hit play

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, windows

Everytime I hit play on the launcher it tries to open then crashes.

using windows 7 professional 32 bit
have uninstalled Java and reinstalled
have uninstalled minecraft and reinstalled.

Here is the error log.

```
15:08:25    game        error   Exception in thread "Client thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$ThreadPerTaskExecutor.execute(CompletableFuture.java:405)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.asyncRunStage(CompletableFuture.java:1632)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.runAsync(CompletableFuture.java:1850)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerBuilder.build(DataFixerBuilder.java:70)
    at xz.b(SourceFile:140)
    at xz.<clinit>(SourceFile:135)
    at aev$a.a(SourceFile:445)
    at aev.a(SourceFile:131)
    at aev.<clinit>(SourceFile:137)
    at pf.c(SourceFile:470)
    at cft.<init>(SourceFile:370)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:144)
  <log4j:Event logger="com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerBuilder" timestamp="1540271305444" level="ERROR" thread="Thread-550">
    <log4j:Message><![CDATA[Unable to build datafixers]]></log4j:Message>
    <log4j:Throwable><![CDATA[java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.InternalError: linkToTargetMethod=Lambda(a0:L,a1:L,a2:L,a3:L)=>{
    t4:L=MethodHandle.invokeBasic(a3:L,a0:L,a1:L,a2:L);t4:L}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1621)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: linkToTargetMethod=Lambda(a0:L,a1:L,a2:L,a3:L)=>{
    t4:L=MethodHandle.invokeBasic(a3:L,a0:L,a1:L,a2:L);t4:L}
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newInternalError(MethodHandleStatics.java:117)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:635)
    at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.callSiteForm(Invokers.java:377)
    at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.linkToTargetMethod(Invokers.java:343)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:314)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
    at abe.makeRule(SourceFile:22)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFix.getRule(DataFix.java:97)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerUpper.lambda$getRule$6(DataFixerUpper.java:136)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerUpper$$Lambda$391/24121840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Map.computeIfAbsent(Map.java:957)
    at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.Long2ObjectMap.computeIfAbsent(Long2ObjectMap.java:606)
    at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.Long2ObjectMaps$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Long2ObjectMaps.java:530)
    at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.Long2ObjectMaps$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Long2ObjectMaps.java:295)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerUpper.getRule(DataFixerUpper.java:131)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerBuilder.lambda$build$1(DataFixerBuilder.java:72)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerBuilder$$Lambda$382/26705850.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1618)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadAndInitializeInvokerClass(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:282)
    at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadMethod(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:274)
    at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.generateCustomizedCode(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:616)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:629)
    ... 17 more
]]></log4j:Throwable>
  </log4j:Event>
15:08:25    monitor Process Monitor error   expected <
22:08:25    com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerBuilder  Thread-3    error   Unable to build datafixers
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.InternalError: linkToTargetMethod=Lambda(a0:L,a1:L,a2:L,a3:L)=>{
    t4:L=MethodHandle.invokeBasic(a3:L,a0:L,a1:L,a2:L);t4:L}
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1621)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: linkToTargetMethod=Lambda(a0:L,a1:L,a2:L,a3:L)=>{
    t4:L=MethodHandle.invokeBasic(a3:L,a0:L,a1:L,a2:L);t4:L}
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newInternalError(MethodHandleStatics.java:117)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:635)
    at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.callSiteForm(Invokers.java:377)
    at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.linkToTargetMethod(Invokers.java:343)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:314)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297)
    at abe.makeRule(SourceFile:22)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFix.getRule(DataFix.java:97)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerUpper.lambda$getRule$6(DataFixerUpper.java:136)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerUpper$$Lambda$391/24121840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Map.computeIfAbsent(Map.java:957)
    at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.Long2ObjectMap.computeIfAbsent(Long2ObjectMap.java:606)
    at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.Long2ObjectMaps$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Long2ObjectMaps.java:530)
    at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.Long2ObjectMaps$SynchronizedMap.computeIfAbsent(Long2ObjectMaps.java:295)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerUpper.getRule(DataFixerUpper.java:131)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerBuilder.lambda$build$1(DataFixerBuilder.java:72)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.DataFixerBuilder$$Lambda$382/26705850.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1618)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadAndInitializeInvokerClass(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:282)
    at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.loadMethod(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:274)
    at java.lang.invoke.InvokerBytecodeGenerator.generateCustomizedCode(InvokerBytecodeGenerator.java:616)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm.compileToBytecode(LambdaForm.java:629)
    ... 17 more
22:08:27    launcher    main    info    
15:08:27    monitor Process Monitor fatal   Process crashed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is in the first line of the crash report

```
15:08:25    game        error   Exception in thread "Client thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

You'll need to go into the launcher settings and allocate more RAM to Minecraft on startup, using the XMX value. I'd recommend no more than half of your total ram, as for some reason minecraft gets strange with more. For most vanilla setups, 2gb (`-Xmx2G`) would be fine.

As soon as I can get to a PC with Minecraft installed, i'll post an image.

Comment: With 32bit java you are limited to at most 4gb but it may be less so 2gb should work.